# MFC, How do I call the system keyboard in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mfc, keyboard

I don't have any method to call system keyboard using MFC code,

Open the system keyboard by manual is

Controller -> easy access center -> Check open keyboard

[system keyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsk465yobx5sw5d/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202014-02-14%2011.13.41.png)

then what code able to open the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a specific call that handles this operation, but it could be created.

Use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open **osk.exe** "On Screen Keyboard" located at *%windir%\system32\osk.exe*

Might also for good measure use

- [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [EnumWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check for any existing open OSK.exe windows and [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to bring it into view.